# Forge To: email header with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, actionmailer

I'd like to send an email from my rails3 application to a set of users but have a dummy To address.

For example:

```
To: Some Entity
From: Some Entity
Bcc: foo@example.com, bar@example.com, baz@example.com
```

However, since ActionMailer leaves it up to the MTA to parse out the email addresses to send to (as opposed to passing an explicit recipient list), the MTA errors on the invalid To: address.

Is there anyway to provide a non-valid address for the To: field with ActionMailer or to divorce the email headers and RCPT list?

Comment: Email Forging in PHP is explained here with Well defined code and Demo, Just Check it out-
[http://democraticprogrammers.com/email-forging-a-php-approach-for-fake-email-generator/](http://democraticprogrammers.com/email-forging-a-php-approach-for-fake-email-generator/)

Comment: @DemocraticProgrammers he's asking about ActionMailer, a Ruby technology, not PHP

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make the `To` address be the same as the `From` address? I think that is what most mailing list systems do.

Comment: This would cause it to send an email to the address in the to field!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling /usr/sbin/sendmail directly.  The message will be sent to whatever recipient address you specify in the command line (this is the `envelope to` address), but you can put any To: address you want in the message headers.  The recipient will see the To: address that you specified in the headers, but the message will only be sent to the `envelope to` address (also known as the RCPT TO address).  This is basically how a bcc works.